# angular dirpagination - get current page

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

I use dirpagination in my angular app to have pagination for my search results. I'm trying to create a dynamic title for the page based on search words and selected page.

```
<h2 class="page-title">{{app.set_page_title()}} - page {{app.pagination.current}}</h2>
```

The problem is I can't get the current page from dirpagination. Any idea how to do it?

Update:

```
  <div class="search-item"
       dir-paginate="item in app.get_results() | itemsPerPage: app.items_per_page">
    <div class="item">
      Lorem ipsum item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left pagination-controls">
    <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
  </div>
```

And this is my app structure:

```
angular.module('searchApp',
               ['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
  .controller('searchController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    var app = this;

    app.set_page_title = function() {
      // Set the page title
      return "Bla bla";
    }

  });
```

Comment: Can you add more code of the template? Is this library for angularjs or angular? is this? https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Comment: Yes. This is the library.

Comment: Aps, ok. I cant help you with that

Comment: I checked better the example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:
- in my controller:

```
app.current_page = 1;
```

and then in my template:

```
<h2 class="page-title">{{app.set_page_title()}} - page {{app.current_page}}</h2>

<div class="search-item" dir-paginate="item in app.get_results() | itemsPerPage: app.items_per_page" current-page="app.current_page">
```